# gnuplot 2d plot to 3d fence plot

Tags: 3d, plot, charts, gnuplot

i have a plot looking like this:

[image: http://www.abload.de/img/selection001yplp.png]

However the lines are overlapping quite a lot and i'm not able to see as much as i'd like. My gnuplot script looks like this:

```
    set autoscale
    set term pdfcairo font ",4"
    set output "plot.pdf"
    set xdata time
    set format x "%H:%M"
    set timefmt "%s"
    set yrange [0:550]
    plot "file.dat" every 150 using 3:4 title '' with lines, \
         "file.dat" every 150 using 3:5 title '' with lines, \
         "file.dat" every 150 using 3:6 title '' with lines, \
         "file.dat" every 150 using 3:7 title '' with lines, \
         "file.dat" every 150 using 3:8 title '' with lines, \
         "file.dat" every 150 using 3:9 title '' with lines, \
         "file.dat" every 150 using 3:10 title '' with lines, \
         "file.dat" every 150 using 3:11 title '' with lines
```

and the corresponding `file.dat` looks like this:

```
(.........)
6 1303238171 0 134.332413 140.304581 138.496323 134.021835 105.546227 107.943008 102.812347 109.098152 972.554886
7 1303238171 0 134.232849 140.35408 138.186279 132.489319 105.941231 108.020004 103.009338 109.75119 971.98429
8 1303238171 0 135.125488 138.125427 138.100098 132.543625 106.153214 107.507042 102.338707 125.25383 985.147431
9 1303238171 0 134.341904 139.913376 138.070648 132.368164 106.214211 108.506859 102.963211 155.246277 1017.62465
10 1303238171 1 134.163055 140.042313 139.231033 132.444244 106.161438 108.850807 103.753929 162.19162 1026.838439
11 1303238171 1 134.179016 140.187561 138.68425 132.572876 107.169006 107.507057 102.974937 120.698692 983.973395
12 1303238171 1 134.40593 140.569382 138.604828 139.589264 106.631699 108.092957 103.634117 108.943863 980.47204
13 1303238172 1 134.353363 138.062759 138.344818 140.665985 107.538544 108.983582 104.300827 175.732117 1047.981995
14 1303238172 1 135.190887 140.411484 138.174591 133.823929 105.412224 108.240623 102.790154 120.459106 984.502998
(.........)
```

Is there an **easy** way to get this chart looking like a fence plot like on the  [gnuplot examples page](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/surface1.html)? I looked over it and it seems to be really complicated. I wish i could easily add a third dimension without changing the `file.dat`. Do you guy's perhaps know a way to achieve this? Or do you have any other ideas how i can make this chart better readable?

Best regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I do not understand your problem correctly. But since you are plotting the time on the x-axis, it seems awkward to make that into a 3d plot, since time is only a one dimensional value. You typically have 3d plots if you are dealing with surfaces (2d-data), where you plot the temperature, pressure or maybe even time against (at least 1d-data).

To make the plot more readable and depending on your data maybe multiplots can lighten things up. Then you can group your data in a couple of plots making it possible to set new ranges for the y-axis?!

If I may point out some simplifications to your script:
Make use of the iteration functionality like so:

```
plot for [i=4:11] "file.dat" every 150 using 3:i title '' with lines
```

And to make that line a little more crisp:

```
plot for [i=4:11] "file.dat" every 150 u 3:i t '' w l
```

And then again, if you do not want a legend in your plot:

```
set key off
plot for [i=4:11] "file.dat" every 150 u 3:i w l
```

Be advised I didn't test the few lines above, so there might be some typos in them^^.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I don't want to plot a surface, i just want to separate the "lines" by using a fence plot like in this example page: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/surface1.html (last third of the page...). Then the x-axis data would be something like 1-8, time would be y and z the other axis.

Comment: @exasam Personally, I don't think your plot will gain from the fence "style". In my opinion you still need some 2D-data which you plot over time (which is then the third dimension). Then again, even if you would plot it that way, some of your plots will overlay others and result in a fancy looking plot but with poor information content.  
Why don't you simply give it a try. Make use of the tutorial in your link and see what you get and if you want to keep it!?

Comment: I've spent a lot of time with this and ended up -- as u predicted -- with the conclusion that fence plots may look fancier but at the cost of loosing informations (due to overlapping graphs). So i decided to split up the data and make mulitplots.